# ComboBox: Binding Error with first item after setting SelectedIndex in code behind

Tags: c#, binding, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I'm really getting crazy. I have a nice Combobox filled up with my CallsItems... bindings works great, but after setting the `Combobox.SelectedIndex = "0"` in code behind, I get error when showing the first entry. (The Combobox Selectionfield stays empty)

1. My Xaml of the Combobox

   ```
   <PivotItem>

   <PivotItem.Header>
       <TextBlock x:Uid="section1"/>
   </PivotItem.Header>

   <Grid Grid.Row="1">
       <ComboBox x:Name="cb_arbeitsplatz"
           x:Uid="arbeitsplatz"
           Header="Wähle Arbeitsplatz"
           ItemsSource="{Binding}"
           Margin="0,6,0,0"
           SelectionChanged="cb_arbeitsplatz_SelectionChanged"
           >
           <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding BEZEICH}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}"/>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding ARBPLATZ}"/>
                   </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       </ComboBox>
   </Grid>
   </PivotItem>
   ```
2. That's my code

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<arbeitsplatz_class> cb_viewmodel = new ObservableCollection<arbeitsplatz_class>();

   public _04_request()
   {
       DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait | DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
       this.InitializeComponent();

       this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

       this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
       this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
       this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;
   }

   public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
   {
       get { return this.navigationHelper; }
   }

   private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
   {
       await JSON_arbeitsplatz.get_JSON("", cb_viewmodel);

       cb_arbeitsplatz.DataContext = cb_viewmodel;
       cb_arbeitsplatz.SelectedIndex = 0;
       ...
   }
   ```
3. This is the error I get from VisualStudio. And it's only for the first Item. All the Rest works pretty fine:

   ```
   Error: BindingExpression path error: 'BEZEICH' property not found on 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[GANTERportal.Data.arbeitsplatz_class, GANTERportal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. BindingExpression: Path='BEZEICH' DataItem='System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[GANTERportal.Data.arbeitsplatz_class, GANTERportal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
   Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ARBPLATZ' property not found on 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[GANTERportal.Data.arbeitsplatz_class, GANTERportal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. BindingExpression: Path='ARBPLATZ' DataItem='System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[GANTERportal.Data.arbeitsplatz_class, GANTERportal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
   ```
4. I can pick the first item. It's shwoing when I'm clicking on the Combobox
   Unfortunately I can't send pictures
5. But choosing the first item will lead to a blank Combobox, due to binding Errors. Again that's only when I'm Setting the Selection of the Combobox from code behind...????
   Unfortunately I can't send pictures

Answer (score 1):

I turns out that a 2nd ListView caused all the mess. I set the SelectedIndex of the Listview as well (no error-message in return), but this caused the Trouble. Removing that - and everything works fine. Now I Need to find a solution how to activate the Combobox AND the Listview...

Comment: @McGarnagle: could you let me know which Using derective I Need to use? And does it work with WindowsPhone 8.1 (RT not Silverlight). P.S.: I couldn't comment your answer?!

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's a few things I'd check/do:

a) put in a check to ensure the ComboBox is populated before the line: Combobox.SelectedIndex = "0" 
b) if possible, set the default selection when the CombBox reports as having completed it's databinding operation.
c) as a test, try one or both of a) default to another index to eliminate the possibility that it's something peculiar to the first item b) see if you can choose index zero from the list when the screen has loaded.

Comment: @maltpm: I've already done that. Nothing changed. I set theSelectedIndex to whatever number. It's allways the first item not showing. I also the a bool in Combobox.Loaded to avoid Setting Index before everything is populated. Again nothing changed. I still have this strange behavior?!